# List comprehension: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, list-comprehension

List comprehension question. I'm parsing a text file with data as shown.

```
sig1 = 1039.0
sig2 = 1034.0, 1035.0, 1036.0
```

With a bit of string manipulation I'm checking if ***sig1*** has multiple values, If yes I'm iterating and appending into a list else just consider as a float.(Example variable sig2)

To cast each value in ***sig2*** into Int, I'm using list comprehension as shown below.

```
i_lst = [int(i) for i in sig2]
```

The issue I'm facing is sometimes ***sig2*** can have only single value and this will be considered as a float variable rather than a list. This messes up the list comprehension and I get below error.

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

How do I overcome this within the list comprehension?

Comment: `[int(i) for i in sig2 if isinstance(sig2, tuple)]`

Comment: @not_speshal, I still have to keep the int casting due to nature of processing that is done after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `sig2` to a list if it's a `float`:

`i_lst = [int(i) for i in ([sig2] if isinstance(sig2, float) else sig2)]`